# Firebase Retrieving a specific data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
  "Company" : {
    "-KRRqrR3Z3R8u1wRW6dd" : {
      "PersonalInfo" : {`
        "address" : "bakakeng",
        "birthday" : "1992",
        "firstName" : "Saoud",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "midName" : "Ahmed",
        "phoneNo" : "12a12a12a",
        "surName" : "Al- Maari"
      },
      "Qualification" : {
        "Degree" : "PHD",
        "Expreince" : "Doctor"
      }
    },
    "-KRS1Jp2hhAbtLNx9jmq" : {
      "PersonalInfo" : {
        "address" : "sfsfsf",
        "birthday" : "sfsfsfs",
        "firstName" : "dfdsf",
        "gender" : "sfsf",
        "midName" : "sfsf",
        "phoneNo" : "123456789",
        "surName" : "jfkldsf"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: How can i retrieve a personal info node if the entered data equals to the phone no. of the personal info??

Comment: What is the language? Swift, Java or JavaScript?

Comment: And organize your data structure

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting a Q.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is your question? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39444632/edit) your question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by a nested child as long as that child is at a fixed path.

In JavaScript:

```
var query = ref.child("Company ").orderByChild("PersonalInfo/phoneNo");
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: I responded in my question but thought I could respond here too. Is this clear in the docs somewhere? I could not find it, time to update some of my models as being able to do this is great!

Comment: We used to have a sample for it on the firebase.com docs, but it looks like that got lost on firebase.google.com. I'll file an issue for that. In the meantime: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html#ordering-queries-by-deep-paths